# Joomla passing parameters when calling an article

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I want to know how I can modify an internal link from an article so as to pass a parameter to a scrap of PHP code in the destination article.

The PHP code embedded in the destination article will use the parameter to identify a record in a database table, then retrieve some data and display it in the article. It is all working, except for passing the parameter from the source article, and retrieving it in the destination article.

I'm using Joomla 2.5.7, with the [DirectPHP](http://www.kksou.com/php-gtk2/Joomla/DirectPHP-plugin.php) plugin to embed the PHP code directly into the destination article.

Comment: can you provide some code snippets please? On a side note, the latest version of the Joomla 2.5 series is 2.5.14, so I suggest you also update it.

Comment: As @Lodder says, definitely update, the latest security fix is **CRITICAL**

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at K2 for Joomla to do this. It has K2 Items which are are like Joomla Articles but have additional fields in them and you can also add extra-fields from the back end.

http://getk2.org